# Slicers not showing up in PowerPivot Gallery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, powerpivot

I uploaded a workbook with pivot charts and slicers to a PowerPivot gallery, the chart shows, but the slicers do not; unless I select "`Edit in Browser`" for the workbook.

What would cause the slicers to not show?  I'm using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise, Excel 2010, and IE 8.

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible that slicer contains more entries, suppose state slicer contains entries more than 50 records.

Details - How to Hook Up the Other Pivot Tables to Your Slicers

1. Build all of the pivot tables that you want to display on your dashboard. Don't start the first pivot table in cell A1 - instead, leave some rows at the top and/or columns at the left.
2. Select a cell in the first pivot table. From the Pivot Table Options tab in the Ribbon, select Insert Slicer. Choose which fields will be used for the slicers. Use the icons in the Slicer Tools Options ribbon tab to change the color, number of columns, and so on.
3. Once the slicers are working and formatted for the first pivot table, select one cell in the second pivot table. Go back to the PivotTable Options tab in the ribbon and look closely at the Insert Slicer icon. When you hover the mouse over this icon, a dropdown arrow appears at the bottom. Open the dropdown and choose Slicer Connections.... Place a checkmark next to each slicer in the list. You've now hooked the second pivot table up to each existing slicer.
4. Repeat step 3 for the remaining pivot tables. You now have a highly visual dashboard without spending a fortune on dashboarding tools.

I hope this helps.

For more information on SharePoint Consulting please contact expertise  at  [www.binaryrepublik.com](http://www.binaryrepublik.com)

Comment: Thanks Navin. This is good advice on how to connect slicers to several pivot tables/charts, and overall good advice on using slicers.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to save the entire workbook to the PowerPivot gallery, before I was only selecting the chart and the slicer. Also, I needed to add the slicer program in the parameters for publish options.

Comment: This looks like an answer to me

Comment: Yea, this is an answer, useful too!